# Error when passing an Array of Objects to Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting strange results when I pass an Array of Objects (Ember Objects or POJOS) to the Ember.Select view helper.

The values populated are apparently Ember object internal properties like: `App.User:ember256`

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dawow/9/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometimes these issues are hard to see, you have a typo, you put:

```
optionValueLabel="content.firstName"
```

instead of:

```
optionLabelPath ="content.firstName"
```

it's optionLabelPath